# I have about 12 virtual servers in NGINX why does NGINX default to one if I don't have one set up for a particular subdomain

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

So I have XX.mysite.com in my DNS but don't have a virtual host set up in NGIX to handle the request...so when I go to the server xx.mysite.com it defaults over to a different virtualhost I have set up on my server like yy.mysite.com.

Just a bit confusing since I don't have xx.mysite.com setup at all.. why does it default to a different subsite..

Comment: See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).